# how to replicate the scenario of master failure manually in mysql

Tags: mysql, perl, replication

How do i manually replicate a master failure scenario?

I have 2 servers that act as master and slave which replicates each other. What i am trying to do is to replicate a scenario of master failure that is, when continuous write happens to master server when master fails. i am accessing the master server using a perl script and inserting values to a table in master server. how can i manually abruptly stop the insertion of data to master server as it would happen when a master is down suddenly.

Comment: Why would you need to do something manually? Won't your inserts fail as soon as you lose your connection to the DB?

Comment: Kill the mysql process?

Comment: i am trying to work on a project that can sync the data between master and slave, if master fails. But in order to do the testing i need to manually kill a server(master) from perl program. I am not sure, how to do it. Do you ahve any suggestion how to kill a server from a perl program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do the following...

1) if the server is running UNIX os .

```
     The perl command would be ..

                system ("ps -ef | grep username| awk '{ print $2 }' | xargs kill -9") ;

             This would kill all the proceeses in your unix server and return to your perl script. Pl note that if you do not want to return to your perl script , use exec command instead of system. Also note that if you are running a database , it would be a better idea to kill your database processes first.
```

2) If you are running a windows server

```
     The perl command would be ..

              system ("taskkill /f /fi username") ;
```

This would kill all the proceeses of the user forcefully of your windows server and return to your perl script.

```
                   Hope This helps
```